# Mapbox rectangle line from bounds from two points

Tags: gps, coordinates, mapbox, rectangles, geo

I use Mapbox and my goal is to create a rectangle from my `bounds`. I also center my map into the `bounds`.

While Mapbox can figure out all my four coordinates for `fitBounds`, it does not do the same thing for the line. Instead it draws the line as a line between the two points.

[image]

**How can I...**

1. ...draw a rectangle instead?
2. ...calculate the other two coordinates needed?

### A part of the code

```js
const bounds = [
  [17.76069212, 59.22761885],
  [18.20001876, 59.44007814],
];

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: "map",
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
});

map.fitBounds(bounds, {
  padding: 16,
});

map.on("load", () => {
  map.addSource("route", {
    type: "geojson",
    data: {
      type: "Feature",
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        type: "LineString",
        coordinates: bounds,
      },
    },
  });
  map.addLayer({
    id: "route",
    type: "line",
    source: "route",
    layout: {
      "line-join": "round",
      "line-cap": "round",
    },
    paint: {
      "line-color": "#888",
      "line-width": 8,
    },
  });
});
```

- I saw turf.js and it seems possible with it, but it's a large library to just draw a rectangle.
- I will accept a library as an answer if it's small.
- If the solution is a math formula, I need a code example to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your pair of bounds coords you always can create a rectangle in mapbox without any library... it's a matter of creating the 4 corners using your data of bottom-left/top-right.
[image]

Mapbox requires to create a fifth point that is the same as the initial one.

Using yours you can create a feature to add to your line layer, and it will paint a rectangle... it would be like this:

```json
{
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          17.76069212, 
          59.22761885
        ],
        [
          17.76069212,
          59.44007814
        ],
        [
          18.20001876,
          59.44007814
        ],
        [
          18.20001876,
          59.22761885
        ],
        [
          17.76069212, 
          59.22761885
        ]
      ]
    ],
    "type": "Polygon"
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {}
}
```

Comment: Oh my! I feel so stupid. I had all the GPS coordinates needed from the start. I just did not see how to put them together. Thanks!

Comment: Not stupid my friend, it happens to me many times too, indeed, the caveat of the fifth coord required by  mapbox is not so obvious